Firebase Cloud Messaging onBackgroundMessage only being called in debug mode, not in production on IOS
When adding a onBackgroundMessage listener to my flutter app, the callback is only being called when debugging not when the app is built for production.
Here is the Firebase Function in Node.js used to send the data-only message:
async function testFunc()  {
    await admin.messaging().send({
      data: {
          question: "NEW",
          theme: "blue",
          type: "widget-question",
          snippetId: "2330hSHHjnsjkqnAn",
          title: "New Snippet",
          body: "TESTNG",
          theme: "blue",
          snippetType: "normal",
          index: "3"

      },
      apns: {
         payload: {
            aps: {
               "content-available": 1
            },
         }
      },
     
      topic: "all"
  })
      
 }

Here is the callback and initializer in flutter:

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future\<void\> \_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
print("Snippets: Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
// If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
// make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);

await FBDatabase(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).addBacklog({
"data": message.data,
});
}

void main() async {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(\_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

runApp(const MainApp());
}

I have Background Fetch and Remote Notifications in my capabilities, and notifications are working fine.
I've tried changing the content-available to 1, but that didn't work. Everything works fine in debug, but not production.
